# Lucida Grande renders differently on Chrome and FF

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

**Screenshot: http://imm.io/Wwr** or http://gasa.jaeh.net

It is pretty evident that my site renders different on Chrome5 and FF3 on my Ubuntu.

Does anybody can point me how can I even these diffs? I don't want fonts with different 'feelings' on each browser.

Another point is, the elements seems smaller on chrome, the font size mainly. Any hints?

**EDIT1**
The font is "Lucinda Grande". The zoom levels seems to be the same (CTRL+0 resets)
Definition:

```
body{ font-size: 18px;font-family: "Lucida Grande";}
```

The rest is defined over percentage

Comment: It looks like one is using Lucida Grande and the other is using a totally different font. How are you calling the fonts just from your local stack, from the google font api or something else?

Comment: @CEich +1 Good question. I made an edit on the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those browsers are using their respective default fonts, which aren't the same. Lucida Grande is not in use at all (it's a sans-serif font, which looks quite different to what you have there). As Lucida Grande is the only font you include in the `font-family` list, the browser must fall back to its default font when this isn't available.

Are you sure you have it installed on your machine? It only normally comes with Mac OS X, not Ubuntu. This is why listing a selection of common fonts is a good idea.

Comment: It does make sense then! I was counting on the computed attributes from the inspector, but then it may not match my installed fonts. I am new to the front-end dev. Thanks